# Stop exim from forwarding email

Tags: email, server, gmail, exim, email-forwarding

Problem;

- I have setup Gmail `split delivery`; one address stays at Gmail while all other addresses for my domain go to my hosting provider. So far so good.
- MX records point to Gmail.
- The hosting provider uses `exim` and all mail coming (routed) from Gmail is being routed back to Gmail (by the hosting provider), ultimately resulting in this error: `Diagnostic-Code: smtp; A delivery loop was detected which causes this email to be undeliverable.`

What I need to do is simply disable this "feature" in exim, so all incoming mail is routed to the corresponding, local, mailbox and not bounced back to Gmail.

I have been researching for a while now and I simply can't find anything to get the job done.

Ideas, suggestions, input would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **must** add your domain as local at hosting provider's side.
If hosting management panel has a facility to add mail domains, just use it.

Comment: thank you. They don't. In fact, they have told me they do not offer any email splitting support at all and that I should do this in the exim configuration itself, of which I have no idea at all.

Comment: So you've got exim under your control at your hosting place?
Is so, you should add your email domain into `local_domains`.
Post your exim's `configure` file and we'll see what might be adjusted.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you George, that was indeed the fix.